# Tensorflow on raspberry pi 3 showing "exceeds 10% of total memory" error

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I have installed tensor flow on raspberry pi 3 but when i'm trying to run an in built classify_image.py example its showing up an error something like this.

```
W0303 12:19:05.695720 1996389072 module_wrapper.py:139] From classify_image.py:146: The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead.

2020-03-03 12:19:10.231787: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:81] Allocation of 8257536 exceeds 10% of system memory.
Killed
```

[raspberry pi ssh screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X0za.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this problem got solved when I reinstalled os in SD card